# 1D wave equation with specified time varying speed

Tags: partial-differential-equations

does anyone know an approach to solve the wave equation with timely varying speed $$\partial_{tt}u-\frac{c^2}{\ell(t)^2}\partial_{xx}u=0$$ where $\ell(t):=L+\epsilon\sin(\omega_s t)$,

$u(x=0,t)=A\sin(\omega_f t)$,

$u(x=L,t)=0$

The parameter $\epsilon$ might be such that $\epsilon<<L$ and we also have $\omega_s<<\omega_f$. So is there an usefull approximation to consider to attack this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll probably want to asymptotically expand your variable $u$ and operators then.

Comment: What is $v(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting, fun little toy that kept me busy for a while. Let's put this into a neater form, first, and see what we can get. A usual wave equation has the form

$$\frac{1}{v_w^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

for a one-dimensional wave with wave function $u(x, t)$ and wave speed $v_w$. Here, we will make $v_w$ now a function of time:

$$\frac{1}{[v_w(t)]^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

Your case corresponds to $v_w(t) = \frac{c}{l(t)\ v(t)}$ (I note a $v(t)$ which looks like it's named "velocity" *multiplying* the timer parameter, is there a mistake there? Just wondering). In any case, we can convert this to a more direct form for the time evolution:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = [v_w(t)]^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

Now in the usual wave equation with steady wave speed, we have the primitive waves as given by

$$u(x, t) = A \cdot \sin(kx - \omega t + \phi)$$

where the relation $\frac{\omega}{k} = v_w$ holds. More easily, if we take "frequency as primary", we have

$$u_\omega(x, t) := A \cdot \sin\left(\omega \left[\frac{1}{v_w} x - t\right] + \phi\right)$$

So as a first guess, we may try to think something similar should work: after all, it does for the constant-speed case, so why should we not have something similar for variable speed? After a number of tries of various things, what I figured was this: suppose we let both the amplitude $A$ and phase $\phi$ vary in time. Then it is easy to see (noting that, in a sense, the evolution of the wave itself is simply a variation on phase!) from the alternative form of solutions to these wave equations, that a solution of the form

$$u_\mathrm{cand}(x, t) := A(t) \cos(kx) + B(t) \sin(kx)$$

might work. In the constant-speed case, $A(t) = \sin(-\omega t)$ and $B(t) = \cos(-\omega t)$, where we have just used the usual relations from the angle-sum formulas for sine. But it turns out that - rather nicely! - this actually works in the variable-speed equation: we have

$$\frac{\partial^2 u_\mathrm{cand}}{\partial x^2} = [-k^2 A(t)] \cos(kx) + [-k^2 B(t)] \sin(kx)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2 u_\mathrm{cand}}{\partial t^2} = [A''(t)] \cos(kx) + [B''(t)] \sin(kx)$$

so taking

$$\frac{\partial^2 u_\mathrm{cand}}{\partial t^2} = [v_w(t)]^2 \frac{\partial^2 u_\mathrm{cand}}{\partial x^2}$$

we get

$$\left(A''(t)\right) \cos(kx) + \left(B''(t)\right) \sin(kx) = \left(-k^2\ [v_w(t)]^2\ A(t)\right) \cos(kx) + \left(-k^2\ [v_w(t)]^2\ B(t)\right) \sin(kx)$$

and can equate the coefficients, and thus give a general solution method for the variable-speed equation as follows.

> **Method:** To solve
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = [v_w(t)]^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
>   use the following steps.
>
> - Given the time-variable velocity function $v_w(t)$, solve the second-order ODE family
>     $$f_k''(t) = \left(-k^2\ [v_w(t)]^2\right) \cdot f(t)$$
>     for a pair of linearly-independent solutions, and call them $A_k$ and $B_k$. (To ensure we get a well-behaved family, make sure to include a consistent initial condition here: e.g.
>     $$\begin{matrix}
>   A_k(0) = 0 & B_k(0) = 1 \\
>   A'_k(0) = -k v_w(0) & B'_k(0) = 0\\
>   \end{matrix}$$
>     which I just chose to generalize off the constant-speed case - but it doesn't matter in terms of expressing power: this is just to make things more concrete and well-defined.)
> - Then write a general solution of the variable-speed wave equation by
>     $$u_\mathrm{gen}(x, t) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [a(k)\ A_k(t)\ \cos(kx) + b(k)\ B_k(t)\ \sin(kx)]\ dk$$
>     where $a(k)$ and $b(k)$ are arbitrary (suitably well-behaved) functions - in effect, a spatial frequency spectrum.

As a check, we will see if this reproduces the expected results from the constant case. If we let $v_w(t) := c$ (a constant speed), then the equation for $A_k$ and $B_k$ is

$$f''_k(t) = -k^2 c^2 f_k(t)$$

which is just

$$f''_k(t) = -\omega^2 f_k(t)$$

with $\omega = kc$. Clearly the solutions

$$A_k(t) = -\sin(\omega t),\ B_k(t) = \cos(\omega t)$$

satisfy the canonicalizing initial value problem, and hence we can write the general solution to the constant-speed wave equation as

$$u(x, t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} [a(k) \sin(\omega t) \cos(kx) + b(k) \cos(\omega t)\ \sin(kx)]\ dk$$

as we would expect, i.e. an arbitrary Fourier series of sine/cosine waves translating uniformly with time. Hence, we consider this solution valid.

**ADD:** However - note that this is for the *free space* case. But the case you give has boundary conditions. For a boundary value problem with two ends, which we will take as

$$u(0, t) = h(t)$$
$$u(L, t) = 0$$

to be consistent with your problem, then we see that we should start again at the particular solutions

$$u_\mathrm{part}(x, t) = a(k)\ A_k(t)\ \cos(kx) + b(k)\ B_k(t)\ \sin(kx)$$

as we need to ensure the boundary conditions hold up for each one individually. Namely, we have

$$u_\mathrm{part}(0, t) = a(k)\ A_k(t) = h(t)$$
$$u_\mathrm{part}(L, t) = a(k)\ A_k(t)\ \cos(kL) + b(k)\ B_k(t)\ \sin(kL) = 0$$

and note we can take $k = \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi}{L}$ to get

$$u_\mathrm{part}(L, t) = b(k)\ B_k(t) \cdot (-1)^n$$

and if we want this $0$, that means we must have $b(k) = 0$. Hence, the general solution for these boundary conditions should look instead like a Fourier-like discrete sum

$$u(x, t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n\ A\left(\left[n + \frac{1}{2}\right] \frac{\pi}{L}, t\right) \cos\left(\left[n + \frac{1}{2}\right] \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)$$

and in this case the coefficients $a_n$ are fixed by the $u(0, t)$ condition

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n\ A\left(\left[n + \frac{1}{2}\right] \frac{\pi}{L}, t\right) = h(t) = C \sin(\omega_f t)$$

and I've just rewritten $A_k(t)$ from before as $A(k, t)$ to make things a bit tidier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Indeed this problem is quite non trivial. I tried many approaches. The only that gave something: consider "brute force" analytical solution defined by part in time, write each reflected ray, sum them up. So we get a series of function with each time an heaviside defined on another subset, and we cannot extract analytically any long time range information from this, as the spectrum or whatever. However since we have something analytical for a first order motion of the boundary, would there not be some first order periodic approximation of the general solution?

Comment: @DgSl : My post gives a general solution algorithm. The trick is solving the ODEs that depend on the velocity function: they will not in general admit analytic solutions, I'd think.

Comment: I still want to know, though, if you have the equation correct - do you really mean to _multiply_ the $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$ term by $[v(t)]^2$, as opposed to _divding_ by it (i.e. multiply by $\frac{1}{[v(t)]^2}$) which, by the symbol "v", looks like it is supposed to be the wave speed?

Comment: Hi and thanks! I updated the settings, something was not coherent. I have the standart speed term of the form $(c/\ell(t))^2$, which corresponds to the $[v(t)]^2$ that you defined. Thus we divide $\partial_{tt}u$ by $[v(t)]^2$ (or we multiply it by $(\ell(t)/c)^2)$

Comment: @DgSl : Or, equivalently, that you have $v(t) = \frac{c}{\ell(t)}$.

Comment: @DgSl : It looks now like the small-$\epsilon$ case does indeed reduce, and involves the so-called "Mathieu differential equation" which is a known problem, with its solutions as 2 well-known special functions but highly non-elementary and difficult to analyze. I'll try to write something on it later.

Comment: I agree, for small $\epsilon$ if we delete the order 2 term, we have $v(t)^2\approx \frac{c^2}{[L^2(1+2\epsilon\sin(\omega_s t)/L)]}$ and then the equations for each $k$: $f_k"=-k^2v(t)^2 f_k$ look more or less like the Mathieu equation. The only way I found to make a clear correspondance (and have something of the form $a-2q\cos(2x)$ as the variable coefficient, cf wikipedia) is to expand in series our approximation of $v$, using $X=2\epsilon\sin(\omega_s t)/L$, which is close to 0. Then we use the expansion of 1/(1+x), and then we get $v$ as a series.

Comment: Then my hypothesis would be to consider $f_k$ as a sum for which each component satisfies the corresponding Mathieu equation with a coefficient which is a term in the series expansion of $v$, and then proceeding with a simple change of variable. Do you think so?

Comment: i.e. considering each $f_k=\sum_i f_{k,i}$ such that $f''_{k,i}=\alpha_i(t)f_{k,i}$ with $v(t)^2\approx\frac{c^2}{L^2(1+\frac{2\epsilon\sin(\omega_s t)}{L})}=\sum_i\alpha_i(t)$. This would return a solution, but we don't have unicity, since assuming that $f_{k,i}$ is a sum is just an assumption